# Unable to Single Log Out from different Domain Clients while using KeyCloak

Tags: .net-core, keycloak, openid-connect, single-logout

I am using KeyCloak Standalone as single Sign on Provider .
I have two dotnet core application hosted at abc.goal.com & xyz..goal.com.
The way I am SLO(single logout) is being done in two steps.  Inside the LogOut Function

```
   1. await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);



 after that

  2. `POST http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/<my_realm>/protocol/openid-connect/logout`
```

This does SLO when localhost but doesn't work when hosted in different domains or when tested on ngrok

Please help , I am stuck

Comment: I believe that it doesn't clear cookies because being in different domain

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#logout), redirect user to URL: `http://auth-server/auth/realms/{realm-name}/protocol/openid-connect/logout?redirect_uri=encodedRedirectUri`

Comment: thanks for the reply...what value should encodedRedirectUri be

Comment: Keycloak will POST to that uri after successful logout, so it depends on what you want to show for a user. It may be a 'success logout' or a main page/screen.

Comment: Could you please give a hint on what happens internally when a client is redirected to mere openid-connect/logout URL .... would it logout from all clients ??? would it clear cookies from different domains & log out all clients who are at abc.com & xyz.com